Solutions for creating presets for reproducible environments?
Currently i'm brainstorming for a solution that would solve the following conundrums:

I want my configuration files for user specific and machine specific items to securely yet easily accessible stored, globally updated when changed, and have some sort of version control feature

Secure & Accessible: i.e. I want to be able to store sensitive informations like ssh keys, api keys, passwords etc. Up until now, for things like API keys, I would use environment variables.
Globally updated: i.e. If I change my .vimrc on one debian machine, it should change for all other debian machines(or as specified).
VCS: I want to be able to rollback updates and whatnot.


I want to be able to create a new environment without much work.

i.e. I've spent countless hours customizing my current linux environment, especially with the window manager. I want to be able to recreate the installations i've done on my current machine to other similar machines without spending much time.



I'm not looking for a single application or technique, just any advice on what to use/do because i'm very sure that these conundrums are common.
